# PHP como por o caminho e o nome de um arquivo em variáveis

Tags: php, arquivo, table, diretório, path

Olá. tenho uma tabela que deve mostrar o nome dos arquivos e a data em que foram atualizados, mas nada aparece.
No HTML tenho apenas

```
<table><?php tabela("/arquivos/formularios/*.*"); ?></table>
```

E no PHP:

```
function tabela($var){
    $globVar = glob($var);  

    for ($i=0; $i<count($globVar); $i++) {
        $caminho = $globVar[$i];
        if (file_exists($caminho)) {
            $nome = basename($caminho,".*");            
            echo "<tr><td class=\"td1\"><a href=\"".$caminho."\">".$nome."</a></td>
<td class=\"td2\">".date("d/m/Y", filemtime($caminho))."</td></tr>";
        }
    }   
}
```

Quando carrego a página, apenas vejo

```
<table></table>
```

Talvez eu esteja entendendo o glob() ou outra função errado. Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Talvez o input da tabela esteja errado. Tente `arquivos/formularios/*.*` caminho relativo em relação ao script

Comment: Era isso mesmo, @gmsantos. Obrigado!

Comment: Logo após a linha `$globVar = glob($var);`, tente exibir os valores contidos no array usando o `print_r` por exemplo. Apenas para verificar se algo está sendo retornado da função `glob()`.

Comment: Oi @AdrianoLeal. Está sim. O problema era o caminho mesmo. Eu não entendo muito bem a diferença entre a \ na frente ou não. Vou procurar isso depois. Obrigado

Comment: Ao menos em ambiente Linux a **/** demonstra que você está buscando a partir da raiz do seu sistema de arquivos, ou seja, do root. Sem utilizar a **/** você busca a partir do diretório corrente da sua aplicação.

Comment: Ele só continua deixando a extensão. O basename() não funciona com ".*"?

Comment: Já sei, acho q dá pra fazer com explode()

Answer (score 1):

porque não usa [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) é muito mais facil

**exemplo:**

```
<?php

/*remove as pastas ".." e "." que podem aparecer em sistemas linux*/
$scan_dir = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__),array("..","."));

foreach ($scan_dir as $file_or_folder) {
    print $file_or_folder."<br/>";
}
```

?>

**output**

```
input.txt
main.php
folder1
folder2
```

Comment: Acho que é uma boa também. Vlw

Answer (score 1):

**Função `tabela()`:**

```
<?php

function tabela($var){
  error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
  $globVar = glob($var);
  $scan_dir = array_diff(scandir($var),array("..","."));
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<thead><th>Nome do Arquivo</th><th>Tamanho do Arquivo</th></thead>";
  foreach ($scan_dir as $file_or_folder) {
    print "<tr><td>".$file_or_folder."</td>";
    if (substr("$file_or_folder", 0, 1) != "."){
      print "<td>".date("d/m/Y", filemtime($file_or_folder))."</td></tr>";

    } else{
      print "</tr>";
    }
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

**Exemplo de Uso:**

```
<?
tabela('./')
?>
```

**Resultado:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Implementada sugestão do @William Borba, na imagem ao invés do tamanho está a data, (detalhe que passou despercebido :))

Comment: Vlw @Ronny. Quando eu tirei a "\" no inicio do caminho, como o gmsantos sugeriu, funcionou. Mas as respostas de vcs parecem mais elegantes que o meu código. Não sou programador, estou começando agora, então preciso dar uma estudada em scandir(). Porém se o pessoal decidir q essa é a melhor resposta, eu marco ela. Abçs. Obrigadão. A você e a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada nesse cara:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.directoryiterator.php

Esse cara tem tudo que você quer é nativo do PHP.

Recomendação: http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/spl-menos-programacao-orientado-arrays/

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Procure contextualizar melhor sua pergunta, exemplificando e explicando melhor como utilizar esse recurso. Aproveite e faça um [tour] para conhecer como as coisas funcionam e leia o guia de [ask]

Comment: Sugestão de leitura: **[Answer]**